# Use the same template for more functions

Tags: c++, class, templates, namespaces, function-templates

I have something like

```
template <typename T>
    T func1() { /* ... */ }
template <typename T>
    T func2() { /* ... */ }
// many other functions which use the same template line
```

If I try this

```
template <typename T>
    T func1() { /* ... */ }
    T func2() { /* ... */ }
```

I get compile error.

Is there possible to write the `template` part only once and make the code working?

Comment: You could wrap those functions into a struct or class

Comment: In the second case: `unknown type name T` for the `func2`. Probably because it recognise the template only for the first function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, in C++ you cannot do that (you can in the D programming language, however), but instead of

```
namespace detail {
    template<class T> func1() { /* */ }
    template<class T> func2() { /* */ }        
}
```

you can use

```
template<class T>
struct detail
{
    static T func1() { /* */ }
    static T func2() { /* */ }    
};
```

This becomes advantageous if you want to simultaneously and partially specialize all functions (you cannot partially specialize function template, but you can for class templates).

**Note**: there is one disadvantage: namespaces are open for new functions, but classes are not, unless you control their source, so you better be sure what to group together.

Comment: Works perfect and it's a complete answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Vlad glad to have been of help!

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned with having to repeat the template parameter declaration too many times you could wrap your functions into a template struct or class

e.g.

```
template <typename T> struct Wrapper {
    static T func1() { /* ... */ }
    static T func2() { /* ... */ }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change your functions signatures, you can make a **define** to do this:

```
#define Templated_T template<class T> T
Templated_T func1() { /* ... */ }
Templated_T func2() { /* ... */ }
```

Its not very C++-ish, but should work correctly.

Comment: now try and refactor T into U. At the very least, use a macro argument

Comment: @TemplateRex whats the point for renaming T info U ? More likely, a need to change 'func1' signature/return type will appear. In case of wrapper it will be more complicated.

Comment: To begin with, the macro is hardly any less typing than writing it out directly. Moreover, using the return type inside the macro is not a good idea either, if you want to add another funnction `template<class T> void func3()` then it won't work.